# combining multiple XML files that have same root element into one single XML file

Tags: xml

Can someone tell me how to combine these 4 XML files into one single file?

Actually each file defines constraints imposed on the same root element called *name*.

I want to actually combine all the constraints for the name element into one single
file. Basically the rules/constraints for the name element should be defined as one 
whole unit (i.e one file defining all the constraints together).

- File1.xml

  ```
  <name use="L"> 
  <prefix qualifier="AC">Dr.</prefix>
  <given>Margaret</given> 
  <given>Ross</given> 
  <family>Ellen</family> 
  </name>
  ```
- File2.xml

  ```
  <name use="P"> 
  <given qualifier="CL">Meg</given> 
  <family>Ellen</family> 
  </name>
  ```
- File3.xml

  ```
  <name use="P"> 
  <given>Margaret</given> 
  <given qualifier="BR">Josephine</given> 
  <family qualifier ="BR">Ross</family> 
  </name>
  ```
- File4.xml

  ```
  <name use="P"> 
  <prefix use="AC">Dr.</prefix> 
  <given>Margaret</given> 
  <given>Josephine</given> 
  <family qualifier="BR">Ross</family> 
  </name>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I would use some kind of mapped data structure, considering you may be doing a large amount of lookups.

Start with parsing each file, store what you need in memory:

Store the "name" as the key, and any other element(constraint?) associated with it in some type of object that you define. While reading each file, you can do a lookup of the name. If the name exists, update the constraints. If it does not, create a new object with the constraints provided in the current file.